# Is there a way to programmatically count RSpec tests?

Tags: ruby, rspec, rake

Given a Rakefile that executes some RSpec tests by way of a `Spec::Rake::SpecTask`, how can I programmatically determine the number of tests that passed, failed, and are pending once the task that ran the tests is finished?

Comment: rspec reports this information for you. why do you need this? what do you want to do with this?

Comment: That information is dumped to `stderr` in a form users cannot consume easily; only a `Formatter` can be used to intercept the information beforehand, but I'm wondering if there's an easier way. Programmatically driving RSpec is a very common operation, so I'm not sure why you seem to be surprised that someone would want to do this. (Otherwise, `SpecTask` wouldn't need to exist!)

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SpecTask is just a nice wrapper around `sh ruby -S spec ...`, so you have no access to the formatter's meta data. You could parse the result, or do the evaluation somewhere else than your Rakefile, or not use SpecTask at all.